# Login User name of computers in LAN java

Tags: java, authentication

I've got the login name of my computer using System.getProperty("user.name"). However, I need the logins of other computers whose IPs I've already got using InetAddress. How do I do it? Displaying the System. properties of all the IPs doesn't display their login names.

Thanks in advance!

All the PCs run on Linux.And I'm looking for the currently logged in user on other machines on the LAN.

I'm pinging all the machines on my LAN to see if a machine is alive. I get it's IP and I want to get its login name as well.

Comment: Are you looking for the currently logged in user on other machines on the LAN? What OS will the users be on, or is it a mixed environment?

Comment: This makes no sense: having an ip address of a computer doesn't mean that anyone is actually logged in on the computer

Comment: @Maurice- I want to know the names of the users who've logged in on active machines.

Comment: Seems like you need to implement LDAP

Comment: you *do* know that you may have several more users than you have IP addresses? Especially on Linux where even the same user can be logged more than once on the same machine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were able to do this "out of the box", this would be a huge security hole in the system. Just think about it. And then we don't even get to the problem of multiple users logged in on the machines.

So without further clarification this question is just too vague.

You can actually log on to the machines in a secure way using ssh, for example, and query the list of logged in users. You need to generate ssh keypairs and use some Java terminal library that can do the login programmatically and issue commands for you.

We actually have a product that works like this (for different purposes), and we use a [3rd party SSH library](http://www.sshtools.com/en/j2ssh-maverick/) to do the hard work for us.

Or, as an alternative, you can implement and install your own "logged-in-users" daemon that you can connect to, perhaps install it as a web application, but then again, you need to use proper authentication to make your service safe to use. This latter solution however requires that an application or at least a web server is running on each machine that you want to query.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution would be to install a software that will listen to a fixed port on the machine. Once you have the machine's address, the program can gather the information and send it back. Other than that, there's no such feature that exists, for various and obvious reasons.

However, even this solution does not guarantee that there will be a listening socket on the listed IP (the software is not guaranteed to be running), so without more information about what exactly you are trying to do, this answer is as vague as the question.

Comment: More info: I'm using Libvirt's Java API and need to connect to the Qemu hypervisors on other machines on my network. This is done by the call qemu+ssh://login.name@IP/system. Until now, I'm able to get the IP of the other machines on my network. Without the login name, I'm not able to connect to Qemu. If I try omitting the login name, it's being replaced with my login name on my PC. Can someone please help me?